# Issue with big array size c++

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, gcc, g++

I have a task for a master course that involves the sampling of probability     distributions via Monte Carlo methods. I want to run some tests before, so I'm sampling the chi square distribution with 2 dof (it can be done with the inverse method). Anyway, I am running into problems with array sizes, anything over ~30000 elements will result with all the points of the probability distribution accumulating at 1, or even with a program crash.

At the end of the post you can see a screenshot of the result with 10000 points and the code I wrote. I have used many versions of the g++ compiler, up to 4.9.2, and none of them worked. The OS is Windows 7. Aaaand the same code works flawlessly in a gentoo computer from a friend. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Manuel J.

[Sampling with 10000 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EehIu.png)

And here is the code I'm using:

```
I've removed it to keep the post shorter. Please see edited code
```

Edit: I've made several changes to the code, the main of which is the transition from plain arrays to vectors, and the problem is still there: anything over ~10000 elements will not work. The problem is definitely the `histograma` function: the contents of the `histo.dat` file when you give it a too large vector are:

```
inf 100000
inf 0
inf 0
inf 0
...
inf 0
```

The code as it is now is as follows. The problem is definitely the max and min functions, but I've not the slightest idea about where the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#define PI 3.14159265359
#define NHISTOMAX 100
#define N 100000
#define GNUPLOT_PATH "D:\\gnuplot\\bin\\gnuplot.exe -persist"
using namespace std;
double max (vector<double> v);
double min (vector<double> v);
void histoplot (string name1);
void histograma (string name, vector<double> v, size_t num2);

vector<double> v(N);

int main (void)
{   
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++)
    v[i]=-2*log(1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX);

    histograma("hist.dat",v,NHISTOMAX);

    histoplot("hist.dat");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void histograma (string name, vector<double> v, size_t num2)
{
    ofstream fileout;
    double max1, min1, delta;
    size_t i, j, num=v.size();
    vector<int> histo(NHISTOMAX);

    if(num2>NHISTOMAX) cout << "Too many intervals. " << endl;

    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<num2;i++)
            histo[i]=0;

        max1=max(v);
        min1=min(v);
        delta=(max1-min1)/num2;

        for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            j=(size_t)((v[i]-min1)/delta); 
            if(j==NHISTOMAX) j--;
            histo[j]++;
        }

        fileout.open(name.c_str());
        for(i=0;i<num2;i++)
            fileout << min1+(i+0.5)*delta << "\t" << histo[i] << endl;
        fileout.close();

        cout << "Histogram generated! Output file: " << name << endl << endl;
    }

    return;
}

void histoplot (string name1)
{
    FILE *gp1;
    gp1=popen(GNUPLOT_PATH,"w");

    if(gp1==NULL)
        cout << "Unable to open pipe. Check gnuplot.exe's path" << endl;

    else
    {
        fprintf(gp1,"unset key\n");
        fprintf(gp1,"set term wxt\n");
        fprintf(gp1,"set output\n");
        fprintf(gp1,"plot '");
        fprintf(gp1,name1.c_str());
        fprintf(gp1,"' w histeps\n");
        fflush(gp1);
        pclose(gp1);
    }

    return;
}

double max (vector<double> v)
{
    double aux=v[0];
    size_t i, num=v.size();
    for(i=1;i<num;i++)
        if(aux<v[i])
            aux=v[i];
    return aux;
}

double min (vector<double> v)
{
    double aux=v[0];
    size_t i, num=v.size();
    for(i=1;i<num;i++)
        if(aux>v[i])
            aux=v[i];
    return aux;
}
```

Edit 2: typical plot of the values in the v vector. All of them positive and under 25.

[Plot of a typical vector obtained.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t067.png)

Comment: By the way, I know that rand() is not the best way to generate random numbers. I use Mersenne Twister when it comes to real fire stuff. I just want to solve this issue with array sizes before :-(

Comment: Try to allocate `v` dynamically, i.e. use `std::vector`.

Comment: I would add a check that `((v[i]-min1)/delta)` is less than `NHISTOMAX`.

Comment: You're right, as they say also down in the answers, I have a stack overflow issue there when v[i]=max1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
#include <vector>
#define N 10000
int main (void)
{
    std::vector<double> v(N); 
    //...
    histograma("hist.dat",v.data(), N, NHISTOMAX);  
    // or
    // histograma("hist.dat", &v[0], N, NHISTOMAX);
```

Note that no change to the `histograma` function itself is required.  The only difference in the call is that `v.data()` (or `&v[0]`) is used to return a pointer to the start of the internal buffer that stores the array of `double`.

In addition, instead of writing `min` and `max` functions, use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` found in the `<algorithm>` header:

```
    max1 = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    min1  = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

or if using C++ 11, [std::minmax_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) to get both:

```
    auto pr = std::minmax_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    min1 = *(pr.first);
    max1 = *(pr.second);
```

Also, if as the other answer suggested, and that you have a memory overwrite, I suggest you change from using `operator [ ]` to using `vector::at()` to access your elements.  Using `at()` will throw an `out_of_range` exception as soon as you make an out-of-bounds access.  Then you fix those errors before converting back to using `[ ]` for the vectors.

For example, this code:

```
        j=(size_t)((v[i]-min1)/delta); 
        if(j==NHISTOMAX) j--;
        histo[j]++;
```

What if `j` is some huge number, far exceeding the bounds of the `histo` vector?  Decrementing `j` by 1 isn't going to help.  To see if this is an issue, `at()` can be used here:

```
        j=(size_t)((v[i]-min1)/delta); 
        if(j==NHISTOMAX) j--;
        histo.at(j)++;
```

If you run the program, if `j` is out of bounds, an exception is thrown as soon as you attempt to increment `histo[j]`.  You can then  inspect the issue and fix the error(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try and do that. Its nice that the functions don't have to be modified, but I think I'll adapt everything I have to vectors instead of arrays, if size is going to be a recurrent problem here.

I only have one doubt left: why is this happening? I mean, I tested the code at another machine, both with gentoo and  archlinux. It worked as a charm with gentoo, and it gave segmentation faults all over with arch. That's why I thought (and still think) it is a compiler issue, as the machine was the same in both cases.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the compiler.  Programs that have these potential runtime flaws will produce programs that have undefined behavior.  Your program would be considered a toy program -- if a C++ compiler can't produce correct executable for such a simple program, it would be run out of the business and laughed at.  So always suspect that there is something wrong with your program, not the compiler.  Unless you can demonstrate with hard evidence that yes, the compiler produced bad code, then the blame is with your program.

Comment: I assume you're right, as I am not an expert, not even close (I'm a physicist, not an engineer). I just thought, given that the code works in a computer, the fault would be elsewhere. 
I'll just stick to using vector from now on, it was about time anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I did the changes you suggested and some others and the problem persists. I've narrowed it down to the max and min functions: when you give them too many elements, they return inf and -0, respectively. That explains the output of histograma (although there could be something else not working, of course). I don't see what could possibly be wrong in such a simple thing!

Comment: Instead of writing `max` and `min` functions, use `std::max_element` `std::min_element`, or `std::minmax_element`.  See my changes.

Comment: I had already tried max_element and min_element from the algorithm library and the problem persists. There is nothing wrong with the vector, I've checked and the maximum value is less than 25, typicaly (and all of them positive; see the image at the question). Also, .at( ) throws no exceptions.

Comment: Then I suggest you debug your code, since the algorithm functions never fail when given the correct arguments.  You were wondering whether it is your own min and max functions were at fault, but you said you replaced them with the algorithm functions.  Using the algorithm functions removes them from the list of things that can go wrong.  So it is something else causing the issue (and I highly advise you **keep** the min_element / max_element calls in your code).

Comment: Turns out I'm even more stupid than we thought. The problem was the vector, some values were inf, but for some reason it wasn't showing in the graphs (maybe gnuplot implements some kind of median filter). A simple filter in the point generation does the trick.
Maybe it was rand( ) to blame a bit, but mostly me. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Ok, rand( ) was definitely to blame. MersenneTwister gives not one single point out of range in 100M. From now on, I solemnly swear that I will not use rand( ), not even for testing.

Comment: The `INF` was probably when `rand()` returns 0 which results in `log(0)` which is undefined. I'm guessing your MersenneTwister RNG results a floating point number which makes an exact `0` result near impossible (but not exactly impossible so be careful).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a potential array overflow at:

```
    delta = (max1-min1)/num2;
   ...
        j = (int)((v[i]-min1)/delta);
        histo[j]++;
```

when `v[i] == max1` this makes `j == num2 == NHISTOMAX` but `histo[NHISTOMAX]` is out of bounds (last valid element is `NHISTOMAX-1` since array indexes start at 0).

Since you tagged your question as C++ I would use `std::vector<double>` instead of raw arrays:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<double> v(N);
...
void histograma (string name, const std::vector<double> v, const int maxHistoSize)
{
     std::vector<double> histo(maxHistoSize + 1);
     ...
     delta = (max1 - min1) / maxHistoSize;
...    

      // There's likely a more C++ idiomatic way to get the min/max of a 
      // std::vector<> but this works fine with a few changes.
double max (const std::vector<double> v)
{
    double minValue = v[0];

    for(int i = 1; i< v.size(); i++) 
    {
         if (minValue < v[i]) minValue = v[i];
    }

    return aux;
}

// Same for min()
```

Comment: You're right, I'll have a stack overflow every time with the max element, thanks! I'll just put it into the last interval.